# Angular and Iframe does not redirect the right window

Tags: angular, iframe, single-sign-on

We have an application in Angular where we need to redirect the user to the login page (when the user is not authenticated or when the token has expired).

We use an HttpInterceptor to handle the 401 HTTP status code (the source code below was of course simplified to make it clearer)

```
@Injectable()
export class AppHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router, private inj: Injector, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {


        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        });

        const changedReq = req.clone({ headers, withCredentials: true });

        return next.handle(changedReq)
            .map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                return event;
            })
            .do(event => {
            })
            .catch((err: any, caught) => {
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    switch (err.status) {
                        case 401:
                          this.document.location.href = <external-url> 
                          return Observable.throw(err);
                        default:
                          return Observable.throw(err);
                    }
                } else {
                    return Observable.throw(err);
                }
            });
    });
}
```

}

Everything works fine when the application is launched from the browser with an URL like `https://localhost:4200`

But now, we need to include our application inside an iframe (we won't be the owner of the parent container).

In order to test our application inside an iframe, we have the following HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Fake Portal</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>My Fake Portal</h1>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <iframe width="100%" src="https://localhost:4200"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

The integration works but when the HttpInterceptor tries to reach the login page with `this.document.location.href`, it redirects the browser instead of redirecting the iframe (and then destroy the parent container).

`this.document` should be the current document and not the top document of the DOM.

Does someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to prevent an iFrame to redirect the browser is by using the sandbox attribute on the iframe tag. In your case you should put something like this:

`<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts">`

This will still allow everything it used to allow, acept for top-navigation (which means changing the parent's url.

You can find more information about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp